# Развертывание слайса в качестве аргумента к методу fmt.Print

Tags: golang

недавно начал изучать golang и столкнулся с такой проблемой.

```
func Print(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
```

Я понял, что метод fmt.Print принимает в качестве аргументов значения с типом пустого интерфейса и создает слайс "a" с типом interface{}, и по факту в метод можно передать переменную любого типа, ведь все типы реализуют пустой интерфейс. Т.е в метод можно спокойно передать слайс с типом int. Но если применить операцию развертывания к интовому слайсу, то метод выдаст ошибку. Почему оно не может принять тип []int, ведь он тоже реализует пустой интерфейс? Хотелось бы подробнее узнать, как работает развертывание

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // func Print(a ...interface{}) (n int, err error)
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    fmt.Print(slice)
    fmt.Print(slice...) //Cannot use 'slice' (type []int) as the type []interface{}
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/0LJsnqSRPTX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция ждет на вход массив интерфейсов а вы передаете массив int, магия не срабатывает т.к. разворачивание слайса приводит к строгому типу на выходе []int вместо ожидаемого []interface{}

Можно вот так:

```
package main

import "fmt"

//внимание на тип принимаемого параметра, не массив интерфейсов, а массив чисел!!!! 
func Cast(s ...int) interface{} {  
  return s
}

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    fmt.Print(slice)
    fmt.Print(Cast(slice...)) 
}
```

Comment: Не понял. Почему функция не может принять массив []int, если тип []int реализует интерфейс?

Comment: ```[]int => interface{}``` ```([]int)... => []interface{}``` разницу видите? оберните руками результат в интерфейс и все сработает ```(([]int)...).(interface{})``` (так записать нельзя, но суть приема из примера в ответе это может помочь понять )

Comment: Еще сильнее запутался... Что возвращает операция развертывания? Массив? И почему после развертывания принимает слайс интерфейсов, а не просто интерфейс?

Comment: Функция ждет на вход interface{}, вы передаете на вход []interface{}, куда проще - я хз...

в первом случае происходит каст одной переменной(среза) в интерфейс, во втором - каст каждого элемента среза в интерфейс. Мой пример - синтаксический сахар который пакует срез ([]int) в один пустой interface{}

Comment: Прочитал несколько статей, теперь стало понятно, что вы хотели объяснить. Из-за операции развертывания функция ожидает не interface{}, а []interface{}. Именно этого я и не мог понять